# WMIC:Auto reply "Y" when wmic command runs through list of computers in .txt document to install program

Tags: wmic

I am currently pushing a .msi to multiple (500+) computers. My WMIC command

```
/node:@"c:\@complist.txt" product call install true,"", "C:\Program.msi" /nointeractive
```

successfully goes through and discards the nodes that wont work. However, once it start the install of the program with the /nointeractive switch, it only installs to the first node(computer). After that, the command stops. Without the /nointeractive switch, it continues after the first install but I have to hit "y" to execute it each time. Is there a way to automate this so that I'm not pressing "Y" 500+ times today or in the future? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.